# What would be the best way to include js file in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am going to create a new project using laravel 5.7.

Project having number of pages(blade templates).

Each blade template having different JS code and for that I want to create separate JS file for each template.

Eg. Let's say there are two templates viz. index.blade.php & edit.blade.php.
And there are two JS files viz. index.js & edit.js

Now I want to include these JS files in their respective templates.

Can anybody suggest me the best way of doing this?

I have used below approach before:

Included JS file manually just before "**/body**" tag.

Also I read about app.js. But writing code in this file, I don't want it to be included in every template.

Comment: You would be better coding all in ONE.js file. Give each page its own function in that file. Then you would only need to load one.js file and it would stay cached on the client

Comment: There are some things which don’t need to be included in every file..eg. including ckeditor. Which to be included in only edit page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How you include include such JS files manually, will depend more on your preference. I will share how I go about it.

In your layout, yield your scripts:

```
<title>@yield('title')</tittle>
...
<div class="content">
    @include('subs.flash')
    @yield('content')
</div>
...
@yield('scripts')
```

On the blade file for the particular page:

```
@section('title', 'Some JavaScript Assets')

@section('content')
    The content of the page
@stop

@section('scripts')
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/custom.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // your inline script
</script>
@stop
```

This allows you to include your external or minified scripts as well.

If you are a fan of packages, [asset pipeline](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline) might interest you.